# how can i recursively place my objects in this tree

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, recursion, tree

I'm trying to write a function called customAdd() that forms the following tree:

```
    let obj = []
    
   let obj1 =  {
    key: "detail1Tests",
    id : "94d3d1a2c3d8c4e1d77011a7162a23576e7d8a30d6beeabfadcee5df0876bb0e"
  }

  let obj2 = {key:"detail1Tests.detail2Tests",id:"5b091b37a9efc9d0567a4beac0bb20fcdf9796f4b71e239da6ac0c53e3488838"}

  let obj3 = {key:"detail1Tests.detail2Tests.detail3Tests",id:"0b60c29d6e309be95ef33b0ad137623c5712a9a47613ce5e561871001c71bd3b"}


  let result = this.customAdd(obj, obj1);
  console.log(result);

  let result1 = this.customAdd(result, obj2);
  console.log(result1);

  let result2 = this.customAdd(result1, obj3);
  console.log(result2);
  };
```

result should hold the value of :

```
children: {
    detail1Tests: [{
            id: " 94d3d1a2c3d8c4e1d77011a7162a23576e7d8a30d6beeabfadcee5df0876bb0e "
            ]
```

result1 should be equal to :

```
children: {
    detail1Tests: [{
            id: " 94d3d1a2c3d8c4e1d77011a7162a23576e7d8a30d6beeabfadcee5df0876bb0e "
            children: {
                detail1Tests.detail2Tests: [{
                        id: "5b091b37a9efc9d0567a4beac0bb20fcdf9796f4b71e239da6ac0c53e3488838"
                    }
                ]
                ]
```

and result2 should be:

```
children: {
    detail1Tests: [{
            id: " 94d3d1a2c3d8c4e1d77011a7162a23576e7d8a30d6beeabfadcee5df0876bb0e "
            children: {
                detail1Tests.detail2Tests: [{
                        id: "5b091b37a9efc9d0567a4beac0bb20fcdf9796f4b71e239da6ac0c53e3488838"
                        children: {
                            detail1Tests.detail2Tests.detail3Tests: [{
                                    id: "0b60c29d6e309be95ef33b0ad137623c5712a9a47613ce5e561871001c71bd3b"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
                ]
```

and so on...

this is the function i built which is only working on the first level:

```
  customAdd(obj , subObj){
    let obj2 = {children: {[subObj.key]: [{id: subObj.id}] }}
    if(obj.children){
      let obj3 = obj.children;
     var kyz = Object.keys(obj3);
     let obj4 = obj3[kyz[0]]
      this.customAdd(obj4 , subObj)
    }
    else {
      return {...obj,...obj2};
    }
   
  }
```

any ideas on how to achieve this is appreciated.

Comment: That's an inefficient data structure to go for. Why arrays? Why not objects keyed by `id`? That will have an impact on searching data in that structure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Function customAdd() had some bugs with what it's trying to achieve. it needs some modifications and it becomes like so:

```
customAdd(obj , subObj){
    
    if(obj.children){
      let obj3 = obj.children;
     var kyz = Object.keys(obj3);
     let obj4 = obj3[kyz[0]]
    return  this.customAdd(obj4[0] , subObj)
    }
    else {
      obj.children=obj2.children;
      return ;
    }
   
  }
```

keeping in mind that the object passed to this function would be modified , so if we need to hold on to result, result1, result2 independently , we need to 'deep copy' the object after passing it to our function and this could be achieved through the syntax:

```
let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

so the code becomes :

```
this.customAdd(obj, obj1);
  var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
  console.log(result);  

  this.customAdd(obj, obj2);
  var result1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));;
  console.log(result1);

  this.customAdd(obj,obj3);
  var result2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));;
  console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a lot like you want to create something like lodash 'set' or ramda 'assocPath'

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set

https://ramdajs.com/docs/#assocPath

Comment: Looks like the lodash set method is a proxy for https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/.internal/baseSet.js

Answer (score 0):

As designreact suggested, this could easily be built atop Ramda's [`assocPath`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#assocPath) (or probably atop the lodash equivalent.)

```js
const customAdd = ({key, ...rest}, o) =>
  assocPath (key .split ('.') .flatMap (k => ['children', k, 0]), rest, o)


let obj1 =  {
  key: "detail1Tests",
  id : "94d3d1a2c3d8c4e1d77011a7162a23576e7d8a30d6beeabfadcee5df0876bb0e"
}

let obj2 = {
  key: "detail1Tests.detail2Tests",
  id: "5b091b37a9efc9d0567a4beac0bb20fcdf9796f4b71e239da6ac0c53e3488838"}

let obj3 = {
  key: "detail1Tests.detail2Tests.detail3Tests",
  id: "0b60c29d6e309be95ef33b0ad137623c5712a9a47613ce5e561871001c71bd3b"
}


const results1 = customAdd (obj1, {})
const results2 = customAdd (obj2, results1)
const results3 = customAdd (obj3, results2)

console .log (results1)
console .log (results2)
console .log (results3)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {assocPath} = R </script>
```

We split the key into parts, and then each part gets a preceding `"children"` and a succeeding `0`, so that, for instance, `"detail1Tests.detail2Tests"` becomes `["children", "detail1Tests", 0, "children", "detail2Tests", 0]`, which is the format used by Ramda's `assocPath`.

But there's no need to pull in Ramda just for this.  It's easy enough to write our own version of `assocPath`, which I've done several times for other questions on StackOverflow, including in [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63996492/1243641).  It is built atop another Ramda-inspired function, `assoc`, and together they look like this:

```js
const assoc = (p, v, o) => 
  Number .isInteger (p) && Array .isArray (o)
    ? [... o .slice (0, p), v, ... o .slice (p + 1)]
    : {... o, [p]: v}

const assocPath  = ([p, ... ps], v, o) => 
  p == undefined
    ? o
    : ps.length == 0
      ? assoc (p, v, o)
      : assoc (p, assocPath (ps, v, o [p] || (o [p] = Number.isInteger (ps [0]) ? [] : {})), o)
```

---

However, I would suggest that you rethink your output structure.  Unless you need that format for consistency with an external system, it's pretty terrible.  This would seem better to me:

```js
{
    detail1Tests: {
        id: "94d3d1a2c3d8c4e1d77011a7162a23576e7d8a30d6beeabfadcee5df0876bb0e",
        detail2Tests: {
            id: "5b091b37a9efc9d0567a4beac0bb20fcdf9796f4b71e239da6ac0c53e3488838",
            detail3Tests: {
                id: "0b60c29d6e309be95ef33b0ad137623c5712a9a47613ce5e561871001c71bd3b"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and could be easily achieved with

```js
const customAdd = ({key, ...rest}, o) =>
  assocPath (key .split ('.'), rest, o)
```

Or, if you really want the `children` node:

```js
{
    children: {
        detail1Tests: {
            id: "94d3d1a2c3d8c4e1d77011a7162a23576e7d8a30d6beeabfadcee5df0876bb0e"
            children: {
                detail2Tests: {
                    id: "5b091b37a9efc9d0567a4beac0bb20fcdf9796f4b71e239da6ac0c53e3488838",
                    children: {
                        detail3Tests: {
                            id: "0b60c29d6e309be95ef33b0ad137623c5712a9a47613ce5e561871001c71bd3b"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you could use

```js
const customAdd = ({key, ...rest}, o) =>
  assocPath (key .split ('.') .flatMap (k => ['children', k]), rest, o)
```

The extra array wrapper seems to add nothing useful.

Comment: thank you for answering , the code in const assoc is throwing a prop is not defined error though

Comment: Sorry.  I know better than to edit code here without an additional test, but somehow I still do it.  It's fixed.